# accessing controller from a seperate directive causing unexpected erros

Tags: angularjs

I am following the joe eames tutorials on pluralsight.  It seems to be fairly straightforward.  I am setting up one directive inside of another, and setting up *** require:  on a child controller***

Here is the code that I have from the demo.  I am using angular 1.5 I haven't changed the $scope to controllerAs as I am focused on figuring out communication between directive controllers.

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

    })

    .directive('swTabstrip', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {},
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.panes = [];
                $scope.select = function(pane) {
                    pane.selected = true;
                    $scope.panes.forEach(function(curPane) {
                        if(curPane !== pane) {
                            curPane.selected = false;
                        }
                    })
                }

                this.addPane = function(pane) {
                    $scope.panes.push(pane);
                    if($scope.panes.length ===1) {
                        pane.selected = true;
                    }
                }
            },
            templateUrl: 'swTabstrip.html'
        }
    })

    .directive('swPane', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                title: '@'
            },
            require: '^swTabstrip',
            link: function(scope, el, attrs, tabstripCtrl) {
                tabstripCtrl.addPane(scope);
            },
            templateUrl: 'swPane.html'

        }
    })
})();
```

The tutorial calls for me to set up directive  **swPane**  to require 'swTabstrip'.   However, I am getting an error in the console

```
3angular.js:13156 Error: [$compile:ctreq]
```

`Controller 'swTabstrip', required by directive 'swPane', can't be found!`

Comment: The `require` property makes a directive look for _controllers_. In your example, you have a _directive_ called swTabstrip. [Read this section of the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually create your tabstripCtrl that your directive uses and at the same time then you can pass it in:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {})
        .controller('tabstripCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.panes = [];
            $scope.select = function (pane) {
                pane.selected = true;
                $scope.panes.forEach(function (curPane) {
                    if (curPane !== pane) {
                        curPane.selected = false;
                    }
                })
            }

            this.addPane = function (pane) {
                $scope.panes.push(pane);
                if ($scope.panes.length === 1) {
                    pane.selected = true;
                }
            }
        })
        .directive('swTabstrip', function () {
            return {
                restrict : 'E',
                transclude : true,
                scope : {},
                controller : 'tabstripCtrl' ,
                templateUrl : 'swTabstrip.html'
            }
        })
        .directive('swPane', function () {
            return {
                restrict : 'E',
                transclude : true,
                scope : {
                    title : '@'
                },
                require : '^tabstripCtrl',
                link : function (scope, el, attrs, tabstripCtrl) {
                    tabstripCtrl.addPane(scope);
                },
                templateUrl : 'swPane.html'

            }
        })
})();
```

If you are trying to share data between your directives, look into services.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.  In  a real project I would use a service, I am just following the tutorial to get a better grasp of communication between directives.